# Error when install packages of WindR in R Studio

Tags: r, linux, package

R Studio Web Service

I want to install a package of Wind API, but there is something wrong:

```
**> install.packages("~/windr.tar.gz",repos = NULL,type = "source")**
Installing package into ‘/home/ying.huang/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘WindR’ ...
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘WindR’
    finding HTML links ... done
    WindR-package                           html  

    finding level-2 HTML links ... done

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpFilhCg/R.INSTALL156610cbb54b/WindR/man/WindR-package.Rd:47: missing link ‘w.w.wappAuth’
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpFilhCg/R.INSTALL156610cbb54b/WindR/man/WindR-package.Rd:48: missing link ‘w.w.wappMessage’
    w.asDateTime                            html  
    w.bbq                                   html  
    w.callback                              html  
    w.cancelRequest                         html  
    w.clearAllRequest                       html  
    w.close                                 html  
    w.demoCallback                          html  
    w.getversion                            html  
    w.htocode                               html  
    w.isConnectionOK                        html  
    w.menu                                  html  
    w.start                                 html  
    w.stop                                  html  
    w.tcancel                               html  
    w.tcovered                              html  
    w.tdays                                 html  
    w.tdayscount                            html  
    w.tdaysoffset                           html  
    w.tdq                                   html  
    w.tlogon                                html  
    w.tlogout                               html  
    w.toperate                              html  
    w.torder                                html  
    w.tquery                                html  
    w.wappAuth                              html  
    w.wappMessage                           html  
    w.weqs                                  html  
    w.wpd                                   html  
    w.wpf                                   html  
    w.wps                                   html  
    w.wsd                                   html  
    w.wset                                  html  
    w.wsi                                   html  
    w.wsq                                   html  
    w.wss                                   html  
    w.wst                                   html  
    w.wupf                                  html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘WindR.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/ying.huang/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/WindR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/ying.huang/windr.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

**My Environment：**

LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
Release:    7.3.1611
Codename:   Core

Comment: The error message tells you that you need to install a library first. From where did you download the package? There should be instructions at that location and/or included in the package.

Comment: So what is the question?